# 3rd party jars at WEB-INF/lib are considered static or dynamic lib

Tags: java, tomcat, dynamic, static, web-inf

I have a Web project (Tomcat) on Eclipse and I have add some 3rd party JARs into the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Due to some license retrictions I cant use libraries as static libraries. But how can I check if libs at WEB-INF/lib folder are static or dynamic?

I know that full project is exported as a WAR file, but before start the execution the WAR is uncompressed to be instaled in Apache.

Comment: To you, what is the difference between a static and a dynamic jar file?

Answer (score 1):

C++ style static and dynamic linking of libraries doesn't exactly apply to Java. The JARs you are including can be thought of as "dependencies".

Some licenses (like LGPL) require that the JAR should be included separately and a new version of the same JAR should be able to replace its previous version. If that is the case for you, you need not worry as Apache is including the JAR as a separate module and loading it at runtime.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805577/when-importing-a-java-library-class-from-jar-is-this-considered-static-linking) for more info.